# При отправки формы регистрации получаю ошибку

Tags: php, yii2

---

Код модели Signup.php

```
public function rules()
{
    return[
       [['email', 'password'], 'required'],
        ['email', 'email'],
        ['email', 'unique', 'targetClass' => 'app\Models\User'],
        ['password', 'string', 'min' => 2, 'max' => 10]
    ];
}

public function signup()
{
    $user = new User();
    $user->email = $this->email;
    $user->password = $this->password;
    return $user->save();
}
```

}

Код контроллера

```
    if (isset($_POST['Signup']))
    {
        $model->attributes = Yii::$app->request->post('Signup');

        if ($model->validate() && $model->signup())
        {
            return $this->goHome();
        }
    }

    return $this->render('signup',
        ['model'=>$model]);
}
```

И view

$form = ActiveForm::begin(['class' => 'form-horizontal']);

$form->field($model, 'email')->textInput(['autofocus'=>true]);

$form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput();

Register

ActiveForm::end();

А вот сама ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну нет такой модели по такому пути. может `models` надо с маленькой буквы? или вообще не написано `use app\models\User;` сверху

Comment: Нигде не прописано в коде app\Models, только с маленькой

Comment: а `use` есть в классе `Signup`?

Comment: Да, Вы были правы, не внимателен. вот тут ошибка 
     ['email', 'unique', 'targetClass' => 'app\models\User'],

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибся в use app\models\User;
Было написано models с большой